# scala/databricks/pyspark: how to parse/format a string based on a pattern?

Tags: scala, parsing, format, databricks, extract

how to parse/format a string based on a pattern which is similar in SQL server with scala or pyspark?

Example,

val string = abcdefg

val pattern= XX-XXX-XX

Then format_string= ab-cde-fg

if val pattern = X-XX-XXXX

Then format_string = a-bc-defg is another example.

I tried substring and others.

Here is my raw initial code:

```
val pattern="XX-XX-XXXX"

val item="abcdefgh"

var lenplus = pattern.indexOf("-")

var fitem=item.substring(0,lenplus)

val result = pattern.split("-")
     
    for ( a <-result )
    {
      val len= a.length() 
      // Displays output
        //println(len)
        
        var sitem= item.substring(lenplus,lenplus + len)
             
        lenplus = len + lenplus
      
        fitem=fitem + "-" + sitem 
      
        //println(lenplus)
      println(fitem)
    }
```

But I received below err message. This is the output and err message

ab-cd

ab-cd-ef

StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 10

Comment: You should show the code that you tried, and explain the specific problem you ran into getting it to work. Also, might help to edit your tags and the question title, as it seems to have nothing to do with pyspark or databricks

Comment: Dima, thanks for your comment. What I tried is far from closer to the solution. That's what I need helps. This need to be done in Databricks or Spark environment.

Comment: Well, that's the problem. SO's scope is answering specific focused questions, not providing complete solutions. You may have better luck on freelancer.com for that.